Copy field of each element in an array of a sub-property to another field
I have a collection of documents in MongoDB that all look similar to this:
{
    "WorkspacePartTeamsite" : {
        "SiteContents" : [
            {
                "_id" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",
                "Name" : "PublicFiles",
            },
            {
                "_id" : "ad57fee3-e478-46a6-a8c1-499dcc98995f",
                "Name" : "Private",
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}

The collection contains hundreds of documents like this.
I would like to update the "SiteContents"-Array and copy the property "Name" to another Property "SPOSegment".
A result could look like this:
{
    "WorkspacePartTeamsite" : {
        "SiteContents" : [
            {
                "_id" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",
                "Name" : "PublicFiles",
                "SPOSegment": "PublicFiles" 
            },
            {
                "_id" : "ad57fee3-e478-46a6-a8c1-499dcc98995f",
                "Name" : "Private",
                "SPOSegment": "Private" 
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}

I tried already to write some queries, but they all do not work.
i.e:
db.collection.updateMany(
  {
    $set: {
      "WorkspacePartTeamsite.SiteContents": {
        $map: {
          input: "$WorkspacePartTeamsite.SiteContents",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$item",
              { SPOSegment: "$$item.Name" }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
)

Any proposal what I can do?

1. Is that your actual updateMany query? Because the first param has to be the documents to find/apply the update to. If it's "all", then you need to have {} like: db.collection.updateMany({}, { $set: ... }). 2. Also, when referencing fields from the document in the update, you need to use the update pipeline syntax: db.collection.updateMany({}, [{ $set: ... }]) Applying that change, your query works: https://mongoplayground.net/p/oA9_giDAtIq


You are missing the first argument which is used to filter the documents to be updated.

As $map is aggregation operator, you should work with aggregation pipeline.


db.collection.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "WorkspacePartTeamsite.SiteContents": {
        $map: {
          input: "$WorkspacePartTeamsite.SiteContents",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$item",
              {
                SPOSegment: "$$item.Name"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Demo @ Mongo Playground

db.collection.updateMany(
    { "WorkspacePartTeamsite.SiteContents": { $exists: true } },
    {
        $set: {
            "WorkspacePartTeamsite.SiteContents.$[elem].SPOSegment": "$[elem].Name"
        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [ { "elem.Name": { $exists: true } } ]
    }
)

